# Should I remove IKernel from my project when also using IWindsorContainer with Castle Windsor?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Based on this statement:

*Castle Project IoC container is offered in two flavors. The MicroKernel, a lightweight container which offers the core functionalities of IoC and DI. Windsor Container, built on top of the MicroKernel and extending its features by adding support for external configuration and interceptors. Most of the times you will end up using Windsor, but to keep things simple I'll start by illustrating how to achieve IoC and DI with the MicroKernel.*

...in [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/InversionOfControlAndDependencyInjectionWithCastleWindsorContainerPart1.aspx) (which, BTW, is the best article I've found for getting an understanding IoC/DI and Castle.Windsor)... I'm thinking I should remove this code from my project:

```
private readonly IKernel _kernel;

public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
{
    _kernel = kernel; 
    // Don't know what to do with the kernel, yet
}
```

...since I also have this:

```
public class WindsorCompositionRoot : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

    public WindsorCompositionRoot(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }
```

Am I right (that I should courtmartial the kernel)?

### UPDATE

Apparently I *should* 86 the kernel, as the sample project for the article noted above has this:

```
//#define USE_KERNEL

. . .

#if USE_KERNEL

        private static void Main()
        {
            IKernel kernel = new DefaultKernel();

            kernel.AddComponent("HttpFileDownloader", typeof(IFileDownloader), typeof(HttpFileDownloader));
            kernel.AddComponent("StringParsingTitleScraper", typeof(ITitleScraper), typeof(StringParsingTitleScraper));
            kernel.AddComponent("HtmlTitleRetriever", typeof(HtmlTitleRetriever));

            HtmlTitleRetriever retriever = (HtmlTitleRetriever) kernel[typeof(HtmlTitleRetriever)];

            Console.WriteLine(retriever.GetTitle(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileUri"])));

            kernel.ReleaseComponent(retriever);
        }
#else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IKernel` is good enough for ControllerFactory purposes. It is good design practice to depend on less details.